# Laravel dd() helper produces error "func_get_args(): Called from the global scope"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I cannot get dd() to work for Laravel 4.1. I was happily coding along and then suddenly dd() just stopped working. It now gives me the following error all the time and terminates my script. I tried commenting out my dd() line and replaced with a simple var_dump() but somehow it still triggers the error with no trace as to where it actually originates.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Here is the full error:

> Warning: func_get_args(): Called from the global scope - no function context in C:\path\to\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 589

Here is the stack trace:

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.2004  137576  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.2008  140984  require( 'C:\path\to\bootstrap\autoload.php' )  ..\index.php:21
3   0.2011  142616  require( 'C:\path\to\vendor\autoload.php' ) ..\autoload.php:17
4   0.2015  153352  ComposerAutoloaderInitcabe389ae891ddbf3368e12fe435e519::getLoader( )    ..\autoload.php:7
5   0.2100  1016440 composerRequirecabe389ae891ddbf3368e12fe435e519( )  ..\autoload_real.php:52
6   0.2109  1128928 require( 'C:\path\to\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php' ) ..\autoload_real.php:61
7   0.2109  1129424 func_get_args ( )   ..\helpers.php:589
```

Right after that error it spits out:

> Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in C:\Apath\to\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line 589

Here is the stack trace for that:

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.2004  137576  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.2008  140984  require( 'C:\path\to\bootstrap\autoload.php' )  ..\index.php:21
3   0.2011  142616  require( 'C:\path\to\vendor\autoload.php' ) ..\autoload.php:17
4   0.2015  153352  ComposerAutoloaderInitcabe389ae891ddbf3368e12fe435e519::getLoader( )    ..\autoload.php:7
5   0.2100  1016440 composerRequirecabe389ae891ddbf3368e12fe435e519( )  ..\autoload_real.php:52
6   0.2109  1128928 require( 'C:\path\to\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php' ) ..\autoload_real.php:61
7   0.2112  1129632 array_map ( )   ..\helpers.php:589
```

Comment: Where did you call it, show the use case.

Comment: " I was happily coding along and then suddenly dd() just stopped " - do you have version control? Roll back until the issue is fixed - then you will know what caused it.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I'm now calling it from nowhere. I deleted the dd() line. I even added an `exit;` line well above where I was last coding and it still gives me this error output. I'm baffled.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I just hit undo several times because I really didn't change much between this error and the previously working copy of the code.

Comment: If you removed that call and still getting the error then it's obviously something else.

Comment: After tracing it back, it appears to be something that has gone wrong in composer independent of the code I was working on, which is odd because I haven't touched composer for this project in nearly a month. Running `composer update` fixed the problem.